# Matlab importdata ignores delimiter and nheaderlines with txt files

Tags: matlab, file-io

I have several txt files that look like this:

```
Experiment ended at 5/8/12 10:00 AM
Number of Tunings 9
0 14.0 82 43.305 
1 34.142857142857146 95 23.432 
2 5.857142857142857 82 31.573 
3 37.42857142857143 83 22.387 
4 5.0 93 14.664 
...etc
```

I want to load this data such that the first two lines are ignored and that I get columns based on space as a delimiter, so the above would become:

```
0  14.0                82  43.305 
1  34.142857142857146  95  23.432 
2  5.857142857142857   82  31.573 
3  37.42857142857143   83  22.387 
4  5.0                 93  14.664
```

The function `importdata(FILENAME, DELIM, NHEADERLINES)`, claimes to do exactly this. However when I call this function with `importfile('pathtofile', ' ', 2)` I get one single string containing all character in the file, so like this:

```
Experiment ended at 5/8/12 10:00 AM Number of Tunings 9 0 14.0 82 43.305 1 34.142857142857146 95 23.432 ...etc
```

How do I get importdata to parse my data correctly?

Comment: The weird thing is that when I rename the files from filenam.txt to just filename (so without the .txt extension) it does seem to work. I do hope that there is another workaround though, because I have quite a lot of files.

Comment: Have you tried import assistent? You can interactively imoort one file and then have it produce the neccesare command for you.

Comment: Is it possible there is a mixture between unix/windows file formats? I'm wondering if in the renaming process you did something like that...

Comment: All files were created on the same windows machine with the same program. I have now batch renamed them, so I least I can go on, but it is weird this function doesn't work.

Comment: the FILENAME string you passed to importdata... does it have .txt at the end of it? Try leaving that off. It could be that it is trying to load filename.txt.txt or something.

Comment: I was loading it with .txt in the name but leaving it out only works if deleted from the filename as well. It seems this bug is only present in 2011 version, in earlier versions it works just fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also use `dlmread` like this:

```
dlmread('filename.txt', ' ', 2, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

`>> help importdata has the following note:`

> If importdata recognizes the file extension, it calls the MATLAB helper
>   function designed to import the associated file format.  Otherwise,
>   importdata interprets the file as a delimited ASCII file.

Maybe the .txt triggers importdata to load the file just as text.  But in my version of MATLAB, importdata works fine on your sample data in a file named .txt.  What version are you using?

If all else fails, you can use copyfile from inside MATLAB to do your renaming

```
fname = 'sample.txt';
barename = regexprep(fname, '\.txt$', '');
copyfile(fname, barename);
importdata(barename, ' ', 2);
```